# Как настроить слайдер в мобильной версии?

Tags: javascript, jquery, слайдер

Подскажите, как настроить слайдер только для мобильной версии сайта?
Есть такой блок:

```
 <section class="etapi_work">
    <div class="inSection">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="img">
                <img src="img/etap_1.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <p class="p-1">Доставка</p>
            <p class="p-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec<br>tetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="img">
                <img src="img/etap_2.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <p class="p-1">Доставка</p>
            <p class="p-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec<br>tetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="img">
                <img src="img/etap_3.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <p class="p-1">Доставка</p>
            <p class="p-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec<br>tetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="img">
                <img src="img/etap_4.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <p class="p-1">Доставка</p>
            <p class="p-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec<br>tetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Нужно, чтобы в мобильной версии он отображался как слайдер. Что делать? Или где читать?

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь [OwlCarousel2](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/started-welcome.html)

Схема работы должна быть примерно следующей - при загрузке страницы вы проверяете `$(window).width()` и если ширина окна меньше нужной вам - то инициализируете карусель, иначе ничего не делаете. 
Плюс можно добавить обработчик - если изменена ширина экрана, то либо оставлять как есть, либо если стало меньше\больше требуемого значения - инициализировать\удалять слайдер. Для удаления можно воспользоваться `owl.trigger('destroy.owl.carousel');`

Answer (score 1):

Используем [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

```
$('.responsive').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: false,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 4,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 6000,
      settings: "unslick"
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю на сколько тут требуется слайдер, многие сейчас делают просто так, может в вашем случае подойдет (работает только на тач устройствах, так что нужно проверять этот фактор тем же modernizer).

```css
.etapi_work {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inSection {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -30px;
  padding: 0 0 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: normal;
 }
```

```html
<section class="etapi_work">
        <div class="inSection">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="img">
                    <img src="img/etap_1.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <p class="p-1">Доставка</p>
                <p class="p-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec<br>tetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="img">
                    <img src="img/etap_2.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <p class="p-1">Доставка</p>
                <p class="p-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec<br>tetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="img">
                    <img src="img/etap_3.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <p class="p-1">Доставка</p>
                <p class="p-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec<br>tetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="img">
                    <img src="img/etap_4.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <p class="p-1">Доставка</p>
                <p class="p-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec<br>tetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```